# What can be said about the definiteness of $A^{T}_i+A_i$ when $\sum_{i=1}^{n}A^{T}_{i}+A_i<0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, positive-definite

Given the matrix $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}A^{T}_{i}+A_i)$ is negative-definite, is it possible to derive any conclusion about the definiteness of $A_i+A^{T}_{i}$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider $n=2$, $A_1=[-2]$, $A_2=[1]$.

Comment: So what's the problem with that?